RippleTheme is deprecated in compose material 1.7.0
RippleTheme is deprecated in material 1.7.0 an has RippleConfiguration replaced it.
How can i use it?

The CompositionLocalProvider is now used to provide a LocalRippleConfiguration instead of a LocalRippleTheme. The migration guide has the following example:
private val MyRippleConfiguration =
    RippleConfiguration(color = Color.Red, rippleAlpha = MyRippleAlpha)

// ...
    CompositionLocalProvider(LocalRippleConfiguration provides MyRippleConfiguration) {
        Button {
            // ...
        }
    }


This is the code listed at the "change [...] ripple for a specific component" docs section, but how is the migration done for the entire app? There's a documentation for it, but I don't understand it.

Replace with
CompositionLocalProvider(
    value = LocalRippleConfiguration provides RippleConfiguration(
        rippleAlpha = RippleAlpha(
            pressedAlpha = 0.2f,
            focusedAlpha = 0.4f,
            draggedAlpha = 0.4f,
            hoveredAlpha = 0.4f
        ),
        color = Color.Black
    )
)

where it will override default indication for all material components and clickable down the tree
for replacing indication of clickable, use ripple() api instead of Deprecated rememberRipple()
   // old implementation

    val ripple = rememberRipple(
        bounded = true,
        radius = Dp.Unspecified,
        color = Color.LightGray
    )

// replace with 
 val ripple = ripple(color = Color.Red, bounded = false)

Refer this documentation

I changed my theme like this and it works:
internal fun RippleTheme(defaultColor: Color) =
    object : RippleTheme {
        @Composable
        override fun defaultColor(): Color = defaultColor

        @Composable
        override fun rippleAlpha(): RippleAlpha = DefaultRippleAlpha
    }

---->
@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class)
internal fun RippleTheme(defaultColor: Color) =
    RippleConfiguration(
        color = defaultColor,
        rippleAlpha = DefaultRippleAlpha
    )

and replace LocalRippleTheme with LocalRippleConfiguration
